# Unity2D: Child class inheriting onCollisionEnter() methods

Tags: unity

I may be an idiot for asking this but I can't seem to solve it myself, I have a GenericWeapon class which has a onCollisionEnter() method which I want applying to all child classes which inherit from it, here is the code:

```
public void onCollisionEnter(Collider target){
    Debug.Log("Collided with player!");
    if(target.GetComponent<Player>()){
        bc2d.enabled = false;
        rb2d.Sleep();
        equip(target.GetComponent<Player>());
    }
}
```

My child class is the following:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RangedWeapon : GenericWeapon
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    { 
    }
    public void attack(){
    }
}
```

and my in GameObject has the RangedWeapon class as a component however the GameObject does not seem to be picking up any collisions with the player. Could someone point out where I'm going wrong with this?

Comment: Are u sure that the problem is form inheritance? if you put the exact `onCollisionEnter` code in the `RangedWeapon` would it work, have u tested it?

Comment: Remember that the method is called OnCollisionEnter, with an uppercase O. If you spell it with a lowercase o, Unity will not call it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use virtual keyword in your GenericWeapon class and make it public.

```
public class GenericWeapon: MonoBehaviour
{   
    public **virtual** void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name.Equals("Cube"))
            print("Parent Hit with cube");
    }
}
```

Then use Override in your Child Class. And Assign Child Class to the gameobject.

```
public class RangedWeapon : CollisionParent
{   
    public override void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        base.OnCollisionEnter(collision);
        print("Child hit with collider");
    }
}
```

This is the way how inheritance work.

Other than this you can use **Delegate**.